# matching a number format regular expression in apache pig

Tags: regex, apache-pig

it is a very simple problem seemingly, how do I match strings of type a-b where a,b vary between 0 and 99.

e.g

```
1234-5678
23-56
1-1
dfv-thy
```

only 2nd and third must match..

as in something like generate (string matches '\d2-\d2') ? 'yes':'no');

Any clues?

Comment: I know one way is to write a udf simply...but is there any inbuilt methodology?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a character class (or `\d` )and limit the repetition :

```
[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/aV1lE2/1

Or as said in comment more precise you can use :

```
\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}
```

Comment: Such a quick reply, let me try this out. Thanks

Comment: \d{1,2}-\d{1,2} is the same, no?

Comment: @Shar1er80 Yes exactly!First that I want to answer I thought it should be done with character class, but seems that it can be done with `\d`'s too.

Comment: oh well thank you so much it worked! I was all looking for the regex syntax here, great help !